# Error texnansi.sty not found

Tags: beamer, pdftex, latex3

I use texmaker on Ubuntu and lately I keep getting some errors when compiling latex beamer files.
In particular, I had an issue with algorithm.sty missing, which was solved after installing texlive-science. Now I get this "texnansi.sty" not found and I don't know why. Anyone has experienced such issues? How did you solve it?

Comment: The catch-all solution through the Ubuntu repository is to install `texlive-full`, which should cover all the packages you may be assumed to have access to as part of a tex distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this kind of thing with `apt-file`:

```
[romano@pern:~] 21s % apt-file find texnansi.sty
texlive-fonts-extra: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ly1/texnansi.sty
```

That means that the missing package is `texlive-fonts-extra`.

Notice that sometimes [you have to manually update](https://askubuntu.com/a/1912/16395) the `apt-file` database, with `sudo apt-file update`.